# ORACLE SQL SYSDATE and between

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get a date using between `SYSDATE` and `SYSDATE - 300`.

```sql
SELECT date_entered
  FROM customer_order_join
 WHERE TO_CHAR(date_entered, 'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN
       TO_DATE(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD') - 300
```

I am getting the following error :

***ORA-01858**: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some strange date conversions in your where clause:

1. To_Char(DATE_ENTERED, 'YYYYMMDD')
   If the column is already a date type just use the column without any conversions and if it is a string, use TO_DATE.
2. TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD')
   No conversion needed
3. TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD')-300
   No conversion needed

So maybe just:

```
SELECT DATE_ENTERED FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_JOIN
WHERE TRUNC(DATE_ENTERED) Between TRUNC(SYSDATE - 300) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

Comment: Never returns a result due to the order of the identifiers `SYSDATE` and `SYSDATE - 300` within the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

`SYSDATE` returns a `DATE` value. Never run `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a `DATE`. Apart from that, `BETWEEN ... AND`  requires the lower date first.

You can compare the `DATE` values directly, I guess you are looking for this:

```
SELECT DATE_ENTERED 
FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_JOIN
WHERE DATE_ENTERED Between SYSDATE-300 AND SYSDATE
```

Most likely you like to compare just the date values, without time value. Then you could use this:

```
SELECT DATE_ENTERED 
FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_JOIN
WHERE TRUNC(DATE_ENTERED) Between TRUNC(SYSDATE-300) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) -- or TRUNC(SYSDATE)+1 to cover full day
```

Note, the query will not utilize an index on `DATE_ENTERED`, unless you have a function-based index on `TRUNC(DATE_ENTERED)`. So you may prefer

```
SELECT DATE_ENTERED 
FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_JOIN
WHERE DATE_ENTERED >= TRUNC(SYSDATE-300) 
   AND DATE_ENTERED < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```